# automation alertmanager receivers

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Good afternoon, maybe someone came across the automation of filling in receivers in alertmanager from custom pod annotations?

I mean, i want alermanager take receivers from pod annotations, like not to do it with hands. For example if namespace is *_* then receivers is getting from custom.io/owner(for example).

I mean can it's look like

```
- name: smthg
  email_configs:
  - to: "__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_custom_io_owner"
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using labels to direct email notifications
A handy feature of the Alertmanager is that almost all notification fields are templatable. This can be used to route emails based on labels.

If you are sending email notifications directly to customers, it'd be useful not to have to create a route and receiver per customer in the Alertmanager. This can be useful whether you are a hosting company providing alerting on the machines you rent out, or the provider of a shared service within a company.

I'm going to presume you already have a working email notification setup, such as was shown previously with Gmail.

We start at Prometheus. We'll need to get the target email address into an alert label. Let's say you have constructed time series looking like:

```
mymetric{job="myjob",email_to="foo@example.org",instance="host1"}
mymetric{job="myjob",email_to="bar@example.org",instance="host2"}
```

Then you can write an alert which propagates this email_to label such as:

```
groups:
- name: test.rules
  rules:
  - alert: MyAlert
    expr: mymetric > 1
```

Now in the Alertmanager we need to do two things. We need to make sure each unique email address gets its own notification via grouping, and we need to make it then go to that email address.

```
route:
  group_by: [email_to]
  receiver: email_router

receivers:
- name: email_router
  email_configs:
  - to: "{{ .GroupLabels.email_to }}"
    from: alerts@example.org
    # Add whatever other settings you need to talk to your SMTP server
    headers:
      subject: "You have {{ .Alerts.Firing | len }} firing alerts"
    html: |
      Hi {{ .GroupLabels.email_to }},

      <p>
      You have the following firing alerts:
      <ul>
      {{ range .Alerts }}
      <li>{{.Labels.alertname}} on {{ .Labels.instance }}</li>
      {{ end }}
      </ul>
      </p>
```

Due to email_to being in the group_by, we can access it via .GroupLabels.  By contrast as alerts with many different Alertname and instance labels could be in this one notification, we have to iterate over them to list t hem all.

https://www.robustperception.io/using-labels-to-direct-email-notifications

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow, please do not copy a whole web page. You might want to explain **in your own words** on how the answer you provided addresses the OP's question.